# How to do Basic Auth using java 8 / scala if we have username and password

Tags: scala, api, java-8

we have username, password and also have api url then how we can Authenticate the api.

```
val auth = Authorizationtype match {
      case Some(addldata) => {
        if(addldata.contains("username") && addldata.contains("password")) {
          val credentials = addldata("username") + ":" + addldata("password")
          Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes)
        }
        else null
      }
```

Comment: I get the way how I can send HTTP Requests with Basic Authentication. I have mentioned one way of knowing. If you know another is more efficient then answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, you can send HTTP requests like this

```
import java.net.{HttpURLConnection, URL}
import java.util.Base64

import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object Example {

def sendRequest(url: String, method: String, additionaldata: Option[Map[String, String]]): String = {

val uri = new URL(url)

// Create a new HttpURLConnection object
val con = uri.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]

// Set the request method
con.setRequestMethod(method)

// Check for token and user token authorization
additionaldata match {
  case Some(addldata) if addldata.contains("username") && addldata.contains("password") => {

    val username = addldata("username")
    val password = addldata("password")

    // Encode the username and password as base64
    val credentials = s"$username:$password"
    val encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes)

    // Add the Authorization header
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", s"Basic $encodedCredentials")

  }
  case _ => // No authorization headers to add
}

// Send the HTTP request
val responseCode = con.getResponseCode()

// Read the response
val inputStream = if (responseCode < 400) con.getInputStream() else con.getErrorStream()
val response = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString

response
  }

}
```